# How can I have a method with default parameters that I can override by name in Groovy?

Tags: methods, groovy, named-parameters, default-parameters

Constructors in groovy allow for named parameters, and method parameters allow for default values, but I can't seem to get a method with default parameter values work with named parameters.

Ideally, I want something like this:

```
def myMethod(def greeting = "Hello", def person = "World", def inflection = "!") {
    "${greeting} ${person}${inflection}"
}

assert myMethod() == "Hello World!"
assert myMethod(greeting: "Hi") == "Hi World!"
assert myMethod(inflection: "?", person: "bob") == "Hello Bob?"
assert myMethod("Sup") == "Sup World!"
assert myMethod("Word", "Dawg") == "Word Dawg!"
```

This is closest I've been able to get, but it's quite ugly and doesn't feel very "groovy" and doesn't fully work in all cases:

```
def myMethod(Map vars = [:]){

    vars.greeting = vars.greeting ?: "Hello"
    vars.person = vars.person ?: "World"
    vars.inflection = vars.inflection ?: "!"

    "${vars.greeting} ${vars.person}${vars.inflection}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed something on your edit to my answer as well. I suppose that is what you meant.

Answer (score 5):

Groovy doesn't have true named parameters, and it won't get better than your last snippet.

Comment: In theory, an annotation (AST Transform, most likely) could be used to create this behavior, right? It looks like a fairly consistent transformation. Something along the lines of the "dirty" map-based version that does the "default named parameters" behavior and then used that to call down to the actual method? (and perhaps a few special case handlers, like `myMethod()`)

Comment: Also, where would I go to suggest adding such a capability to the language?

Comment: You could drop a word in the mailing list. Also there is the GEP - [Groovy Enhancement Proposal](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GroovyJSR/Groovy+Enhancement+Proposal). There is [this issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4) (one of the first ever) and as it states, the JVM doesn't support it. Scala does it, though, but either it saves some metadata or it is a compiler verified thing.

Comment: I implemented such a transform some years ago (https://github.com/pniederw/groovy-extensions), but it wasn't accepted into the language due to a concern that it wouldn't be possible to make it work as well as if it was a first-class language feature. If you want to see support for true named parameters (I certainly do), you can add a JIRA issue, vote on an existing issue, and/or make some noise on the mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

This will, if it is not uglier. :)

```
def myMethod(Map params = [:], String... args) {
    "${params.greeting ?: args?.size() > 0 ? args[0] : "Hello"} ${params.person ?: args?.size() > 1 ? args[1] : "World"}${params.inflection ?: args?.size() > 2 ? args[2] : '!'}"
}

assert myMethod() == "Hello World!"
assert myMethod(greeting: "Hi") == "Hi World!"
assert myMethod(inflection: "?", person: "Bob") == "Hello Bob?"
assert myMethod("Sup") == "Sup World!"
assert myMethod("Word", "Dawg") == "Word Dawg!"
assert myMethod("Word", "Dawg", '?') == "Word Dawg?"
assert myMethod(greeting: "Hi", person: 'John') == "Hi John!"
```

And here's a version that is a bit more dev-friendly, and is a bit more obvious in how it maps to the desired method signature:

```
def myMethod(Map params = [:], Object... args) {

    def greeting = params.greeting ?: args?.size() > 0 ? args[0] : "Hello"
    def person = params.person ?: args?.size() > 1 ? args[1] : "World"
    def inflection = params.inflection ?: args?.size() > 1 ? args[1] : "!"

    "${greeting} ${person}${inflection}"
}
```